# Looking for a way to update Windows drivers using a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to find a way to update drivers using a batch script. I've cobbled together some different things to get the hardware ID's of the various devices in the system, but I cannot find a way to get the windows command devcon to update the drivers using the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
cls

REM *** Checking for admin permissions ***
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM *** If error flag set, we do not have admin ***
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( 
    goto gotAdmin
)

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"


REM *** Variables ***
SET loc=\\artsfac.arts.ualberta.ca\install$\testing
SET IDFile=%loc%\All.txt
SET IDFileNum=%loc%\AllNum.txt
SET HWIDFile=%loc%\HWIDs.txt
SET SearchText="Hardware ID"

REM *** Checking connection to artsfac ***
net use \\artsfac.arts.ualberta.ca
cls

REM *** Checking if devcon is in System32 ***
IF NOT EXIST C:\Windows\System32\devcon.exe copy %loc%\devcon.exe c:\Windows\System32 > NUL 2>&1

REM *** Getting proper Hardware ID's ***
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ECHO.
ECHO Retrieving current Hardware ID's. Please wait...
devcon hwids * | findstr /n .* >> %IDFile%
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /c:%SearchText% %IDFile%') do (
    set /a next=%%a+1
    ECHO !next! >> %IDFileNum%
)
for /f %%a in (%IDFileNum%) do (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in (%IDFile%) do (
        if %%a==%%b (
            SET HWID=%%c
            SET HWID=!HWID: =!
            ECHO !HWID! >> %HWIDFile%
        )
    )   
)
endlocal
cls

REM *** Get current driver folder location ***
ECHO.
ECHO Enter full path for driver folder location (local drive only).
SET /P driverdir=": "

REM *** Update all listed devices ***
ECHO.
ECHO Updating drivers. This may take a while...
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%HWIDFile%) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir "%driverdir%\*.inf" /b /s') do (
        devcon updateni "%%a" "%%b" > NUL 2>&1
    )
)

REM *** Remove temp files ***
del %IDFile%
del %IDFileNum%
del %HWIDFile%

shutdown -r -f -t 20
```

So, everything in this code works properly (albeit in a fairly ugly manner) except for the part where I call **devcon updateni**. All I get (if I remove the redirect) is a huge number of "devcon failed" messages and nothing gets updated. However, if I take one of the hardware ID's and the specific INF file it needs and feed those into the devcon updateni command it works. So, what am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible that either device hardware IDs (although I don't think so) or the path to the .inf files contain spaces?

Comment: @CristiFati Oops, I forgot that I had quotes around the %%a and %%b. I've updated the code above to reflect that.

Comment: Do you know `DPInst32.exe` for x86 and `DPInst64.exe` for x64 drivers? No, search in www for those two free Microsoft applications to install driver packages. Those two executables are used by many driver installers (in background) to simply install all driver files in a folder. Make the directory with the driver files the current directory and run `DPInst*.exe` and the driver package installer installs the driver files independent on number of `*.inf` files needed to be installed for the hardware (network adapters usually have multiple INF files).

Comment: @Mofi I wish I could hug you right now. This is perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

@Mofi had the solution of using the [Driver Package Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544842.aspx) (DPInst.exe) to install the driver packages.

To be thorough, here's the script I ended up writing that works:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET loc=<location of the files>

REM *** Checking for 32bit or 64bit ***
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (
    set drivercmd=%loc%\dpinst64.exe
) ELSE (
    set drivercmd=%loc%\dpinst32.exe
)

ECHO Please type the full path to the driver folder.
SET /P folder=": "
ECHO.

ECHO Installing drivers. Please wait...
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /a:d /s /b "%folder%"') do (
    %drivercmd% /s /sh /path "%%a"
) 

shutdown -r -f -t 0
```